# Typescript Error: Variable 'resWithStatus' is used before being assigned. ts(2454)

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, try-catch-finally

```
for (const item of filesForUpload) {
  let resWithStatus: IResponseType;
  try {
    const res = await uploadFile(item);
    resWithStatus = {
      id: res?.id,
      name: res?.name,
      link: res?.link,
      ext: res?.ext,
      status: "SUCCESS",
    };
  } catch (err) {
    resWithStatus = {
      id: uuidv4(),
      name: item.name,
      link: URL.createObjectURL(item),
      status: "FAILED",
    };
    console.log(err);
  } finally {
    const indexInUploadedImageState = newFileArray.findIndex((imageItem) => {
      if (
        resWithStatus.status === "FAILED" &&
        imageItem.name === resWithStatus.name
      )
        return true;
      if (
        resWithStatus.status === "SUCCESS" &&
        getFileNameWithoutExt(imageItem.name) === resWithStatus.name &&
        getFileExt(imageItem.name) === resWithStatus.ext
      )
        return true;
      return false;
    });

    console.log(resWithStatus); // Error occurs here
  }
  console.log(resWithStatus);
}
```

So I have this piece of code written in TS, I have declared a variable with let keyword with type inside the loop body, but I'm still getting the **Error**: `Variable is used before it is assigned`. As far as I know shouldn't this variable `resWithStatus` be available in all blocks of try, catch and finally as it's declared outside of them and used inside them. I'm fairly new to TS but get that it's not able to reference the outer `resWithStatus` variable which I don't get why.

Comment: Can you provide a working example with this error? Maybe on codesandbox or similar.

Comment: @MarcoNisi  I can give you the context. This whole loop is inside of an async function. We perform some async task with uploadFile method and inside of loop I have declared the variable and I try to set it to some value in either `try` or `catch` and then try to use the value stored in that variable inside of finally block as the variable itself was declared outside of try, catch and finally block with let keyword. But when I try to access that variable in finally block, TS throws the error `Variable is being used before it is assigned` but it would be assigned something in either blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about the `try`, `catch`, and `finally` having access to the `resWithStatus` variable. But the error is saying `resWithStatus` is used before it is assigned. And I think in this case, since `resWithStatus` is not initialized(`let resWithStatus: IResponseType;`), TS can't guarantee that it has a value when it is being read from in your `finally` block. I think something like

```js
let resWithStatus: IResponseType = {/*initialize resWithStatus*/};
```

should fix it.

Comment: This fixed the issue but wouldn't something be assigned to variable in either try or catch block? What other path is there where it could not be assigned any value before it reaches finally block?

Comment: You know that, I know that, but the compiler can't be sure of it. What if you have some other code before assigning a value to `resWithStatus` in the `catch` block and that code threw an exception? That's the way I can explain it. I'm sure someone who has more knowledge about TS compiler can explain in a more precise way.

Comment: Even in this case, when `URL.createObjectURL(item)` throw an exception, `resWithStatus` would be undefined when the code reaches the `finally` block.